# Алгоритм определения релевантности результатов поиска

Tags: поиск

Довольно интересно, существует ли определенный мат. аппарат или теория для определения релевантности. Если нет, то какая существует аналитическая почва у алгоритма определения релевантности. Конечно, можно написать и свой примитивный алгоритм, но хочу разобраться с этой темой, так как известно, что нет смысла изобретать велосипед.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует. И достаточно много алгоритмов. Если делать простенький поиск, то можно (и, наверное, даже лучше, чтобы разобраться, как всё работает и т.д) вывести свою формулу, например: Сумма( `1/частота_появления_слова_в_тексте + 1/порядок_слова_в_запросе + 1/длина_слова` ) для каждого слова в запросе. Также можно учитывать слова которые идут рядом.

Перед тем как применять формулы ревалентности, можно применить фильтр Стемминга для текстов перед индексацией и для запроса. Если нужно находить схожие статьи, можно применить Латентно-семантический анализ, применить сингулярное разложение и т.д. Всё зависит от того, что именно вам нужно.

А если это нужно для какого-то проекта, к которому нужен серьёзный подход - рекомендую применить уже готовые решения, например [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html) или другие ...

Comment: Спасибо за полный ответ. Пока просто хочу разобраться с алгоритмами поиска нахождения схожих материалов. Сейчас почитаю про Латентно-семантический анализ и применить сингулярное разложение.
Можете немного более подробно рассказать про поиск похожих статей?

Comment: Не так давно проскакивала замечательная статья на Хабре про этот алгоритм: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/algorithm/110078/